# The certificate data cannot be read with the provided password, the password may be incorrect when running ASP.NET Core Kestrel on Linux

Tags: asp.net, docker, ssl, ubuntu-16.04, kestrel

I created self signed SSL certificates by following this tutorial:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/configuring-https-in-asp-net-core-across-different-platforms/

I am using Linux `Ubuntu 16.04 LTS`

It is `ASP.NET 5` application and I am running it in `docker`.

So this are steps. I created file https.config

```
[ req ]
default_bits       = 2048
default_md         = sha256
default_keyfile    = key.pem
prompt             = no
encrypt_key        = no

distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
req_extensions     = v3_req
x509_extensions    = v3_req

[ req_distinguished_name ]
commonName             = "localhost"

[ v3_req ]
subjectAltName      = DNS:localhost
basicConstraints    = critical, CA:false
keyUsage            = critical, keyEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage    = critical, 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1
```

Then generated private key:

```
openssl req -config https.config -new -out csr.pem
```

Then created certificate

```
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -extfile https.config -extensions v3_req -in csr.pem -signkey key.pem -out https.crt
```

And finally generated pfx file:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out https.pfx -inkey key.pem -in https.crt -password pass:mypassword
```

I pass location and password to give Kestrel info about certificates and it fails on password check altought password is ok. I think it loads the certificate because when I put another path of the file I get another error.

```
sudo docker run  -p 50205:443 -e "ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80;https://+:443" -e "ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/https.pfx" -e "ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=mypassword" -v /home/vlado/Desktop/https.pfx:/https/https.pfx   622
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue. In my case, it was caused by special characters in my password being interpreted as an escape sequence.
I resolved it by setting a password for the certificate that doesn't include special characters.